# AngularJS duplication of dependencies due to use of iframes

Tags: angularjs, performance, iframe, dependencies

Working on an Angular App, i have a main module(.js), called by a main index.html which has a lot of script tags to include dependencies.

For business reasons, i had to use Iframe , to display pages that are out from this module.  So i call another index.html , which also has a lot of script tag.

But this list of script tags is the same as main.html's . So each dependecy is loaded twice.

Is there a way to use the already loaded dependency for my iframes html pages instead of reload them ?

The goal is to reduce loading time after refreshing a page , ( without cache )

Comment: Did you refer any link like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718127/illegal-use-of-ngtransclude-directive-in-the-template?

Comment: If on server you have right settings for static resources (*.js, *.css, etc.) -- loading time will be same.